# Continue main thread if worker thread returns unhandled

Tags: .net, multithreading, reflection

I'm using reflection to instantiate objects from other assemblies. the objects in these assemblies may start other threads throughout the course of their process. the author of this assembly may fail to correctly handle exceptions on these worker threads.
The problem is, that when they do return unhandled, the whole application ceases to execute and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` is triggered.

I've tried simply wrapping my method invoker in a `try...catch` but that does not seem to catch the exception (makes sense as the next spawned worker thread is the actual failing thread)

Is there a way to handle this situation without simply mandating that developers handle all exceptions correctly?

The idea would be similar to the way windows services work. just because a single app fails, doesn't mean that the Windows Service Host should crash also.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You really should just mandate that exceptions are handled correctly in the threads, and if not, shutdown your application cleanly.

In order to prevent the AppDomain from shutting down, you would need to load these "components" within their own private AppDomain.  This would cause them to tear down their AppDomain, but not the entire application.

This has other consequences (particularly with passing data into and out of the objects), and will potentially dramatically complicate your application's design, so it's not something I would undertake lightly.